# Progress Dial Scroll plus CSS overlap on 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

Can someone help me out I am not sure how to solve this, I need to convert this graph 
http://codepen.io/swizenfeld/pen/vmggpy.

```
// circle: https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

$(document).ready(function() {
  // animate 'card-remaining' box
  $('.card-remaining').addClass('card-remaining-active');

  // add circle chart
  $('.card-goalchart').circleProgress({
    startAngle: 1.5 * Math.PI,
    lineCap: 'round',
    value: .9,
    emptyFill: '#5a5959',
    fill: {
      gradient: ["red", "orange"]
    }
  });

});
```

Image attached of what the final should look like.

1. Make it so it progressed at you scroll down the page
2. As it scroll for the gradient to change different colors
3. When it is at 100% I need the end of it to overlap over the beginning of the graph with a shadow.

not required to use the current JS library if you have a different one that works too

[image]

Comment: this looks like a full job which we can find on freelance sites. Consider posting this job on one of those site?

Comment: Thanks, i was hoping someone had something similar I could reuse at least get me closer to it